# VSTO: How to trigger the Check Names action in Active Mail item

Tags: c#, .net, email, outlook, vsto

I'm creating a Microsoft Office 2013 Add-in that does some behaviour similar to the Address book in an Active Mail item:

[image]

I'm working with **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem** and using the **Recipients** property, and the **Recipients.ResolveAll()** method to load and remove addresses to it, everything seems to work fine until I click OK on my loaded from so I send control back to the active mail Item. At this point Outlook goes crazy and doesn't place the addresses properly in the To or the CC, or some of them go missing.

I'm thinking that one solution to the problem could be to trigger the Check Names when the user is ready to click OK and send all the addresses from my form to the Active mail item.

How can I trigger this action / button?

I couldn't find anything that could do that in the MailItem class. I would like something similar to this (but to use from within my poped-out windows form in Outloook):

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

**UPDATE:**

This are some bits of my code to add more context:

I use the method AddRecipientToActiveItem for each item that I have. It will verify if it already exists (it was already added), if not it will resolve it and if it is correct add it.

```
  private void AddRecipientToActiveItem(string recipientAddress, Recipients recipientList, OlMailRecipientType recipientType)
        {
            Recipient recipientObject = default(Recipient);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(recipientAddress) && !EmailRecipientAlreadyExists(recipientAddress, recipientType))
            {
                recipientObject = recipientList.Add(recipientAddress);
                recipientObject.Resolve();
                if (recipientObject.Resolved)
                {
                    recipientObject.Type = (int)recipientType;
                    recipientList.ResolveAll();
                }
                else
                {
                    recipientObject.Delete();
                }
            }
        }
```

for this, I have to iterate through each element in the list of recipients and compare by address + type (From,To,CC,BCC) pair:

```
private bool EmailRecipientAlreadyExists(string fullEmailAddress, OlMailRecipientType recipientType)
{
  foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient recipientObject in ActiveMailItem.Recipients)
        {
            if (GetRecipientEmailAddress(recipientObject) != null)
            {
                if (GetRecipientEmailAddress(recipientObject).Equals(fullEmailAddress) && recipientObject.Type == (int)recipientType)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

  }
```

But the user can also add addresses to their email item manually, and some of them exist in the exchange server, but others are simple smtp address, so when comparing I have to handle both scenarios:

```
    private string GetRecipientEmailAddress(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient recipientObject)
{
    Outlook.ExchangeUser objExchangeUser = null;
                 if (recipientObject.Address != null && recipientObject.AddressEntry != null)
            objExchangeUser = recipientObject.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
        if (recipientObject.Address == null && objExchangeUser == null)
            return recipientObject.Name;
        if (objExchangeUser == null)
            return recipientObject.Address;
        return objExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
    }

}
```

It seems like this what I've done is not enough to keep consistent states of the email addresses when I read them from the mail item and put them in a text box of my form, then add more addresses and send them back to the mail item and close the form, and repeat the process.

Answer (score 1):

The Namespace class provides the [GetSelectNamesDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867382.aspx) method which obtains a [SelectNamesDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861560.aspx) object for the current session. It displays the Select Names dialog box for the user to select entries from one or more address lists, and returns the selected entries in the collection object specified by the property SelectNamesDialog.Recipients.

```
 Sub SelectRecipients() 
  Dim oMsg As MailItem 
  Set oMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
  Dim oDialog As SelectNamesDialog 
  Set oDialog = Application.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog 
  With oDialog 
   .InitialAddressList = _ 
   Application.Session.GetGlobalAddressList 
   .Recipients = oMsg.Recipients 
   If .Display Then 
    'Recipients Resolved 
    oMsg.Subject = "Hello" 
    oMsg.Send 
   End If 
  End With 
 End Sub
```

The dialog box displayed by [SelectNamesDialog.Display](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868361.aspx) is similar to the Select Names dialog box in the Outlook user interface. It observes the size and position settings of the built-in Select Names dialog box. However, its default state does not show Message Recipients above the To, Cc, and Bcc edit boxes. For more information on using the SelectNamesDialog object to display the Select Names dialog box, see [Display Names from the Address Book](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863291.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Eugene. I think I missed something in my question and it was that my form autogenerates email addresses based on a list of items I read from my database, so they are not in the global address list (hence why I'm using a separate form to add new addresses to the mail item). So if the user searches for foo in my form and he finds the records foo1, foo2 and foo3, he can select and add foo2 to the To: and that will add foo2@mydomain.com he can also add foo3 to the CC: and it would become foo3@mydomain.com, then he will click ok and that will move the addresses to the mail item.

Comment: .. so it's never real people or contacts what I will add, only autogenerated email addresses that the email server will deal with after the user sends the item